# GridLayout inside ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ViewPager` (that takes up 2/3ths of the screen using the `layout_weight` property) where each page is a `GridLayout`.

Now I find it nearly impossible to find out the correct amount of columns and rows needed to make the `GridLayout` fill up nicely in a screen independent way.

Each cell in the grid has a `View` that is 150dp by 150dp (this does not have to be that exact value but it has to be a square).

I tried finding out the the width of the grid or pager (using `getWidth()`) but it returns 0 for each of the calls. Using the width I thought I could calculate the amount of cells I could fit in the Grid depending on the used screen.

Is there any good way of trying to solve this `android layout` problem?

Thank you.